# MapServer UVraster layer with two data sources

Tags: mapserver, mapfile

I have wind data that I want to use in a UVraster layer.  The problem I have is that my data for the U and V components are in separate files.

While I know I could combine the U and V files into one that has all the data, I'd like to avoid that to simplify my pipeline down the road.

I saw a passing reference in the MapServer documentation on raster files that implied I could have more than one DATA line in the LAYER definition.  What I can't find any information about is how you would actually use those two DATA lines in a layer definition.

Here's an example of a working layer definition using a single data file:

```
    LAYER
        NAME "SURFACE_CURRENT"
        GROUP "Oceanography"
        METADATA
            "wms_title" "Surface Current"
            "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326"
        END #metadata
        PROJECTION
            "init=epsg:4326"
        END
        TYPE POINT
        STATUS ON
        CONNECTIONTYPE uvraster
        DATA "../geotiff/currents.tif"
        PROCESSING "BANDS=1,2"
        PROCESSING "UV_SIZE_SCALE=7.5"
        CLASS
            STYLE
                SYMBOL "arrow-start"
                SIZE [uv_length]
                COLOR 255 0 0
                ANGLE [uv_angle]
            END #STYLE
        END #class
    END # layer
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
    LAYER
        NAME "SURFACE_WIND"
        GROUP "Met"
        METADATA
            "wms_title" "Surface Wind"
            "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326"
        END #metadata
        PROJECTION
            "init=epsg:4326"
            "lon_wrap=180"
        END
        TYPE POINT
        STATUS ON
        CONNECTIONTYPE uvraster
        DATA "../geotiff/u_file.grib2"
        DATA "../geotiff/v_file.grib2"
        PROCESSING "BANDS=u_file:1,v_file:2"
        PROCESSING "UV_SIZE_SCALE=7.5"
        CLASS
            STYLE
                SYMBOL "arrow-start"
                SIZE [uv_length]
                COLOR 255 0 0
                ANGLE [uv_angle]
            END #STYLE
        END #class
    END # layer
```

Is this sort of construction even possible?

Comment: It sounds like using TILEINDEX would solve your approach - see https://mapserver.org/input/raster.html#rasters-and-tile-indexing

Comment: I don't think so... my problem is that the two components needed for the uvraster are in different files, not that I want to make tiles out of one dataset...  I would like to eliminate the need to process those files to make a single raster file with both components.